# Template de arquivo para IDE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Boa noite pessoal.

No Netbeans, ao clicar com o botão direito do mouse em qualquer arquivo é possível criar um template com a opção Salvar como Modelo...

O Eclipse tem essa opção?
Se não tiver, existem algum plugin que faça isso?

Answer (score 2):

Desse modo você pode mudar os templates de arquivo Web do eclipse, é só selecionar o tipe New File.

1. Clica em Window > Preferences.
2. Expande a Linguagem que você queira
3. Expande editor
4. Selecione Templates

Você pode checar como criar na documentação do eclipse
http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_codetemp.htm

Caso queria cria um modelo para java voce deve:

1. Clica em Window > Preferences.
2. Expande a "Java"
3. Expande "Code Style"
4. Selecione "Code Templates"

Você pode checar a documentação aqui: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fref-preferences-code-style.htm

Comment: Olá Victor. Eu preciso criar template de arquivo, os passos que você passou é para criar template de código.